# Why is my for loop just not running?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have no idea why my for loop is not running in this function. It just gathers the val from all the different text forms that are dynamically created and should push them to the array.

However as of right now the .push is not working because the for loop is not running at all. Any thoughts as to why this is?

```js
$('#calc').on('keyup', '.sideInfo', function() {

  if (i == 1) {
    console.log('false');
    return false;
  } else {
    var data = [];
    var totalLoan = [];
    var minLoan = [];
    var months = [];
    for (var j = 1; j < i; j++) {
      console.log('hi');
      var total = $('.total-amount' + j).val();
      var min = $('.minPay' + j).val();
      console.log(min);
      var numMon = +total / +min;
      totalLoan.push(total);
      minLoan.push(min);
      months.push(numMon);
    }

    var sideTot = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < totalLoan.length; i++) {
      sideTot += +totalLoan[i];
    }

    console.log(sideTot);
    $('#sideTot').text(sideTot);
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="amount" class="total-amount1 qForms" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="8" placeholder="Total amount of loan" />
  </div>
</form>

<tr id="rowTabLow">
 <td>Total</td>
 <td id="sideTot" class="sideBot">F</td>
 <td id="sideMin" class="sideBot">T</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Where do you set `i` ?

Comment: what is the value of "i" , where is i setted up ?

Comment: Also you're redefining i inside your loop.

Comment: i = 1 at the beginning and changes based off of how many text fields are on the page but is never lower than 2 when there are text fields on the page.

Comment: @Frank Show how you set it in your code snippet.

Comment: Why don't you just give all the inputs the same class, and use `$(".classname").each()`?

Comment: @Barmar - you're right, I'm stupid, thanks man that's what did it.

Answer (score 1):

If `i = 0` your `for` loop will not run.

Also - if `i = 1` your for loop will not run.

What is the value of `i`?

You might need to change your for loop to

```
for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++)
```